# "slotchange" event doesn't trigger at iOS 11

Tags: web-component, lit-element

I need to detect the moment when a slot content rendered into my web component. I use `slotchange` event to track it. It works fine for all the browsers except iOS 11 (for iOS 13+ works ok). Could someone suggest how to do it properly?

So from the next code, I expect to see "firstUpdated" and "slotchange" messages in the console after the page is rendered. But for iOS 11 I have only "firstUpdated".

```
firstUpdated() {
  console.log("firstUpdated");
  const slot = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("slot");

  slot.addEventListener("slotchange", () => {
    console.log("slotchange");
  });
}
```

Here is a sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-litelement-vanilla-wy61t?file=/src/index.js

and URL to see the result:
https://wy61t.csb.app/

Comment: I say this is a question for the (Apple) developers: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Safari handled slot change events wrong - firing them before the elements were added to the DOM. I think `firstUpdated` is firing after the slot change has. Try using `@slotchange=${...` syntax instead, though even if that works it will fire out of order.

If that fails you may have check for the `assignedElements` manually to work around the Safari bug.